# Is there a Cantor set in $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ with positive Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory, fractals

Is there a Cantor set in $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ with positive Lebesgue measure?

Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: What about $C \times C$ where $C$ is a Cantor set in $[0,1]$ with positive measure ?

Comment: Product cantor sets with positive measure are actually very important in dynamical systems; they are used, for example, in the proof of accessibility of partially hyperbolic maps in the recent work of Avila, Crovisier, and Wilkinson.